# Getting all references to a view within a project on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

Given a view or a table, how can I list views and scheduled queries having a reference to it within a project?

I understand from [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-views) that I can do check reference within a dataset with below query, but I'd like to check reference within a project all at once.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_dataset_name.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(view_definition, 'your_dataset_name.your_table_name')
```

Comment: If you have a table opened by Dataset DS1 in project P1 then could you not have a view in Dataset DS2 in project P2?  If that were possible, then asking for the list of reference within a project isn't necessarily going to capture ALL references.  I get the sense that to achieve reference listing by projects you would generate a list of all datasets in your project and then for each dataset generate a list of any references to the source table.

Comment: You may write python program to fetch list of all datasets from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA and then loop through INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS schema. OR take all dataset name in string, plug in excel and use string formulas with union all to create union all for each dataset and execute that query.